# Using PushKit without CallKit will not terminate the app any more on Xcode 11.3

Tags: push-notification, callkit, pushkit

I know that with Xcode 11 if we use PushKit then we must use CallKit as well, otherwise the app crashes.

Currently, I use Xcode 11.3 and it seems that PushKit works without CallKit. Does anyone know if something is changed?

In the past, when I was using PushKit without CallKit, it was crashing right away and a message was shown telling me that I must use CallKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to answer my question here since I got answer from apple.

Nothing change, the developer must use CallKit, it seems there is issue with Xcode 11.3 that not showing warning to the users but however after a while the operative system avoid showing push to the user.